# MySQL Table backup size difference after restoring the table in target server

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, innodb

I have two MySQL RDS machine, I have taken single table Dump from One RDS and restore the same table in second RDS, My Question is Source RDS table size : 50 GB Target server table size 35 GB (After restored the Destination RDS server)

I have checked table count from both RDS (Source & Destination) Counts of records are same. But size only different Can someone clarify the issue?

Comment: If you haven't done an `OPTIMIZE TABLE` recently, the original DB has lots of wasted space which goes away when you restore.

Answer (score 0):

Not a problem.

When you modify (Insert/Update/Delete) rows, the underlying B+Tree gets rearranged in seemingly random ways.  Growing from 35 to 50 and staying at 50 seems likely for the way a BTree works.

The "dump" you took probably generated `INSERT` statements, fetched in `PRIMARY KEY` order.  The resulting dump file can be bigger *or* smaller than the disk footprint of the actual table.  This is due to how the various datatypes are stored versus dumped.

Another thing to note:  `SHOW TABLE STATUS` (or the UI equivalent) will show the number of Rows -- but that is only an *estimate*.  Do not trust it for comparing; instead, use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl` to count the actual number of rows.  (But be aware that that is slow on a 50GB table.)